# Access the history of a task using the Conduit API

Tags: phabricator

I want to be able to use the Phabricator Conduit API to get historical information about a task such as when it was assigned/unassigned and when it moved columns on a workboard.

I've looked through the Conduit API [Documentation](https://phabricator.karenware.com/book/phabricator/article/conduit/) and I'm able to give a Project PHID and get information on the current state of the tasks on the workboard, but not their history.

This is an example of the information I'd like to get back through the API [image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`maniphest.gettasktransactions`](https://secure.phabricator.com/conduit/method/maniphest.gettasktransactions/). It's a frozen method, but I don't see any modern methods to get this info.

Example result:

```
{
  "2059": [
    {
      "taskID": "2059",
      "transactionID": "36573",
      "transactionPHID": "PHID-XACT-TASK-4fyapons4cxspcv",
      "transactionType": "core:columns",
      "oldValue": null,
      "newValue": [
        {
          "columnPHID": "PHID-PCOL-l47qpqaqky5cucv53jtj",
          "boardPHID": "PHID-PROJ-ogxwp55og5rqok56vmot",
          "fromColumnPHIDs": {
            "PHID-PCOL-azcgsgut44vew2sfqhh7": "PHID-PCOL-azcgsgut44vew2sfqhh7"
          }
        }
      ],
      "comments": null,
      "authorPHID": "PHID-USER-gimad45egg7tcccxd6co",
      "dateCreated": "1556545748"
    },
    {
      "taskID": "2059",
      "transactionID": "36572",
      "transactionPHID": "PHID-XACT-TASK-y2fjn5yzby4mdz6",
      "transactionType": "core:edge",
      "oldValue": [],
      "newValue": [
        "PHID-CMIT-idy5uamuuz3eespdsmvd"
      ],
      "comments": null,
      "authorPHID": "PHID-USER-gimad45egg7tcccxd6co",
      "dateCreated": "1556545665"
    },
    {
      "taskID": "2059",
      "transactionID": "36382",
      "transactionPHID": "PHID-XACT-TASK-rwanaewpmqpzslc",
      "transactionType": "core:subscribers",
      "oldValue": [
        "PHID-USER-2clcr42jsfygiyne64kq",
        "PHID-USER-whapfbsypxiafuoy3wi5",
        "PHID-USER-gimad45egg7tcccxd6co"
      ],
      "newValue": [
        "PHID-USER-whapfbsypxiafuoy3wi5",
        "PHID-USER-gimad45egg7tcccxd6co"
      ],
      "comments": null,
      "authorPHID": "PHID-USER-2clcr42jsfygiyne64kq",
      "dateCreated": "1555615023"
    },
    [...]
```